# Filtering Form Fields - OctoberCMS

Tags: forms, filter, model, field, octobercms

Can anyone help me on this please?

I am trying to filter the form field "Switch" in the list view,

**Below is the fields.yaml :**

```
fields:
    support_riyadh:
        label: Riyadh
        span: left
        type: switch
    clm_support_riyadh:
        label: 'No. of Nursing Support From Riyadh'
        span: auto
        trigger:
            action: show
            field: support_riyadh
            condition: checked
        type: text
```

**Below the function called in model:**

```
public function filterFields($fields, $context = null)
    {  if ($this->value == 0)
        {
            $this->trigger->field->value = 0;
        }
    }
```

I am getting this exception :

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property MOH\KPI\Models\NursingSupport::$trigger has no effect

E:\Xampp\htdocs\mohkpi\plugins\moh\kpi\models\NursingSupport.php line 54
```

I want to change the value of the **triggering form field** from the corresponding form field.

Regards